# Автоматическое создание объекта при доступе к полю?

Tags: javascript

Иногда возникает задача в некой переменной определить глубоко вложенное поле. Например, функция:

```
function My(a) {
  a.b.c.d = 2;
  return a;
}
```

Но нет гарантии, что объект имеет нужную нам структуру. В указанную функцию можно передать такой объект:

```
const test = {
  b: {
    c: {
    }
  }
}
console.log(My(test))
```

или такой:

```
const test2 = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 1
    }
  }
}
console.log(My(test2))
```

Но такой код приведет к исключению:

```
const test3 = {
  b: {
  }
}
console.log(My(test3))
```

Конечно, можно переписать функцию так:

```
function MyPlus(a) {
  if (!a) a = {};
  if (!a.b) a.b = {};
  if (!a.b.c) a.b.c = {}
  a.b.c.d = 2;
  return a;
}
```

Но можно ли как-то написать красивую версию, чтобы по мере доступа через точку (или еще как) к очередному полю, если его нету (undefined) создавался пустой объект?

Comment: в lodash есть именно такой метод: [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/#set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть немного странная идея, но не уверен что стал бы использовать это в продакшне

```js
function MyPlus(a) {
  ['b', 'c', 'd'].reduce(function(obj, ix) {
    if (obj[ix] !== Object(obj[ix])) obj[ix] = {};
    return obj[ix];
  }, a);
  a.b.c.d = 2;
  return a;
}

console.log(MyPlus({b: {c: null}, e: 123}));
console.log(MyPlus({b: null, e: 123}));
```

Или еще страшнее

```js
function MyPlus(a) {
  ['b', 'c', 'd'].reduce((o, ix) => (
    (o[ix] = o[ix] !== Object(o[ix]) ? {} : o[ix]), o[ix]
  ), a);
  a.b.c.d = 2;
  return a;
}

console.log(MyPlus({b: {c: null}, a: 123}));
console.log(MyPlus({b: null, e: 123}));
```

Чтобы устанавливать значение внутри объекта по заданному пути, можно сделать такую функцию:

```js
function setByPath(obj, path, value) {
  let last = path.pop();
  path.reduce((o, ix) => (
    (o[ix] = o[ix] !== Object(o[ix]) ? {} : o[ix]), o[ix]
  ), obj)[last] = value;
  return obj;
}

a = {
  b: null,
  d: '123'
};
setByPath(a, ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 4);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть много кода где нужно делать подобные операции можно написать такой хелпер

```js
var o = {
  x: {
    lala: 1,
  }
}

function SetDeep(obj,deep,value) {
  var parts = deep.split(".");
  var current = obj;
  for(var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++ ) {
    var v = parts[i];
    if(!current[v]) {
       current[v] = {};
    }
    current = current[v];
  }
  var v = parts[parts.length-1];
  current[v] = value;
}

SetDeep(o,"x.y.z.e",2);

console.log(o);
```